# Passing data to another activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I am developing a QR Code app for android. I want to pass whatever I scan into a new activity. This is my QR Code results code,

```
 public void handleResult(final Result result)
{
    final String scanResult = result.getText();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scanned Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton ("Show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultPage.class));
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(scanResult);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

ResultPage.class is the activity I wish to display the scanned result on to, how do I do this? Edit: My ResultPage.Class is currently empty with only an empty textview. I'd like the output to be in the textview.

Comment: use Intent for data passing between two activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String scanResult = result.getText();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ResultPage.class);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", scanResult);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can find scanResult in ResultPage activity

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

Comment: Hello, for the String s line, where do I put the code in ResultPage?

Comment: Inside your onCreate() of the ResultPage.class

Comment: The show button brought me to the resultpage.class but it was blank.

Comment: Debug your code and check what is the value of scanResult before putting it at intent.putExtra and the check is this same at oncreate of ResultPage.class.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the value of scanResult?

Comment: value of scanResult string .

Comment: Ah I see, I finally did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have URI then pass that URI using Intent

if you want to pass image itself

```
Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in another activity receive like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
image.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the Resulted string from `MainActivity` to `ResultPage`.
For passing the data from one Activity to Another Activity, you can use `Bundle`.

Here is the code for sending data to another Activity:

```
builder.setNeutralButton ("Show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultPage.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("RESULT",scanResult);
            intent.putExtra(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And now you can get this result to `ResultPage` Activity.
Here is the code for getting data.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String scanResult = bundle.getString("RESULT");
```

Now you can Display your `scanResult`.